# git create manually patch from somewhere

Tags: git, patch

i couldt compile the ninvaders game. When i searched the error on google, i found a solution here https://sourceforge.net/p/ninvaders/bugs/2/ .
Suggestion for the solving problem as below(you can also check from the link also):

```
diff --git a/aliens.c b/aliens.c
index fa87c5c..6c42676 100644
--- a/aliens.c
+++ b/aliens.c
@@ -26,6 +26,19 @@
#include "player.h"
#include "nInvaders.h"

+Aliens aliens;
+
+int shipnum;
+
+// todo: move to structure
+int lowest_ship[ALIENS_MAX_NUMBER_X];
+int alienshotx[ALIENS_MAX_MISSILES];
+int alienshoty[ALIENS_MAX_MISSILES];
+int alienshotnum;
+int alienBlock[ALIENS_MAX_NUMBER_Y][ALIENS_MAX_NUMBER_X];
+
+int bunker[BUNKERHEIGHT][BUNKERWIDTH + 1];
+
/*
* initialize aliens attributes
/
@@ -163,7 +176,7 @@ void render()
aliens.right=-1;
aliens.bottom=-1;
shipnum=0;
- for (k=0;k<11;k++) {
+ for (k=0;k<ALIENS_MAX_NUMBER_X;k++) {
lowest_ship[k]=-1;
}

diff --git a/aliens.h b/aliens.h
index 040d93f..a746414 100644
--- a/aliens.h
+++ b/aliens.h
@@ -37,23 +37,23 @@ struct Aliens {
int bottom;
int speed; // 0: no movement; 1: one per turn; etc.
};
-
-Aliens aliens;
-
-int shipnum;
+
+extern Aliens aliens;
+
+extern int shipnum;

#define ALIENS_MAX_NUMBER_X 10
#define ALIENS_MAX_NUMBER_Y 5
#define ALIENS_MAX_MISSILES 10

// todo: move to structure
-int lowest_ship[ALIENS_MAX_NUMBER_X];
-int alienshotx[ALIENS_MAX_MISSILES];
-int alienshoty[ALIENS_MAX_MISSILES];
-int alienshotnum;
-int alienBlock[ALIENS_MAX_NUMBER_Y][ALIENS_MAX_NUMBER_X];
+extern int lowest_ship[ALIENS_MAX_NUMBER_X];
+extern int alienshotx[ALIENS_MAX_MISSILES];
+extern int alienshoty[ALIENS_MAX_MISSILES];
+extern int alienshotnum;
+extern int alienBlock[ALIENS_MAX_NUMBER_Y][ALIENS_MAX_NUMBER_X];

-int bunker[BUNKERHEIGHT][BUNKERWIDTH + 1];
+extern int bunker[BUNKERHEIGHT][BUNKERWIDTH + 1];

void aliensReset();
diff --git a/nInvaders.c b/nInvaders.c
index 793139c..2afe398 100644
--- a/nInvaders.c
+++ b/nInvaders.c
@@ -32,6 +32,11 @@

#define FPS 50

+// todo: let's try to not having to declare these "public"
+int weite;
+int level;
+int skill_level;
+
int lives;
long score;
int status; // status handled in timer
diff --git a/nInvaders.h b/nInvaders.h
index 1161321..161d370 100644
--- a/nInvaders.h
+++ b/nInvaders.h
@@ -46,10 +46,10 @@ void drawscore();
void doScoring(int alienType);

// todo: let's try to not having to declare these "public"
-int weite;
-int level;
-int skill_level;
-
+extern int weite;
+extern int level;
+extern int skill_level;
+
// included from globals.h
extern void doSleep();
extern void showUsage();
diff --git a/ufo.c b/ufo.c
index 928872b..1d747c0 100644
--- a/ufo.c
+++ b/ufo.c
@@ -27,6 +27,7 @@
#include "nInvaders.h"

static int fShowUfo = 0;
+Ufo ufo;

/**
* initialize ufo attributes
diff --git a/ufo.h b/ufo.h
index 60dc493..05447da 100644
--- a/ufo.h
+++ b/ufo.h
@@ -34,7 +34,7 @@ struct Ufo {
int posY; // vertical position of aliens
};

-Ufo ufo;
+extern Ufo ufo;

void ufoReset();
int ufoShowUfo();
```

i just created a patch file named as `error_fix_patch.patch` and just copy and paste the above code to the file. When i apply patch from this file(`git apply error_fix_patch.patch`). It gave me the below error:

```
error: corrupt patch at line 6
```